# python создать словарь требуемого вида

Tags: python, классы, словари

Помогите написать функцию или модифицировать имеющyюся функию чтоб создать словарь согласно классу.

Должен создаться следующий словарь.

```
{folder1.arg: {file2.arg: None, file3.arg: None}, folder2.arg: {file4.arg: None}, folder3.arg: {folder4.arg: {file5.arg: None}}, file1.arg: None}
```

Код программы.

```
class file_system(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(file_system, self).__init__()
        self.arg = arg
        self.inside = None
        self.root = False


computer_1 = file_system("computer_1")
computer_1.root = True
folder1 = file_system("folder1")
folder2 = file_system("folder2")
folder3 = file_system("folder3")
folder4 = file_system("folder4")
file1 = file_system("file1")
file2 = file_system("file2")
file3 = file_system("file3")
file4 = file_system("file4")
file5 = file_system("file5")
computer_1.inside = folder1, folder2, folder3, file1
folder1.inside = file2, file3
folder2.inside = file4
folder3.inside = folder4
folder4.inside = file5


def tree(value, tab=" "):
    if value.root is True:
        print(value.arg)
    if value.inside is not None:
        if type(value.inside) == tuple:
            for item in value.inside:
                print(tab, item.arg, sep="")
                tree(item, tab=tab + " ")
        else:
            print(tab, value.inside.arg, sep="")
            if value.inside.inside is not None:
                tree(value.inside, tab=tab + " ")
    else:
        return


tree(computer_1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вам такая реализация:

```
class file_system(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(file_system, self).__init__()
        self.arg = arg
        self.inside = None


computer_1 = file_system("computer_1")
folder1 = file_system("folder1")
folder2 = file_system("folder2")
folder3 = file_system("folder3")
folder4 = file_system("folder4")
file1 = file_system("file1")
file2 = file_system("file2")
file3 = file_system("file3")
file4 = file_system("file4")
file5 = file_system("file5")
computer_1.inside = [folder1, folder2, folder3, file1]
folder1.inside = [file2, file3]
folder2.inside = [file4]
folder3.inside = [folder4]
folder4.inside = [file5]


def tree(value, tab=" "):
    if value.inside:
        return {value.arg : [tree(inside) for inside in value.inside]}
    else:
        return {value.arg : None}


print(tree(computer_1))
```

Правда там в качестве значение на свойство делается список.
Кстати `None` - это логически отрицательная величина, поэтому не надо писать: `if value.inside is not None:`

Comment: Спасибо, это отлично

Comment: @pelmenx, если вам подошел ответ то проголосуйте **ЗА**